# linux programable interval timers

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

Let's assume below scenario:

In the multi-processor system we have, PIT that interrupt any cpu in system and its update 
jiffies value which get protected by `write_seqlock(&xtime_lock)`.
When all CPU receive PIT interrupt they do jiffies++.  In this case if we have 4 CPU, the value of jiffies is incremented by 4 ticks at each one tick, therefore our time is not true.
Is this scenario true or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find my question i hope it is useful for you.
There are two components in the Intel APIC system, the local APIC (LAPIC) and the I/O APIC.
we know due of LAPIC bu about I/O APIC
I/O APICs contain a redirection table, which is used to route the interrupts it receives from peripheral buses to one or more local APICs.
(it is from wikipedia)
there for just one cpu recieve interupt or in some case more than one.
thank for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

i belive this can true in unerstand linux kernel ebook below text mentioned: 
The local APIC timer sends an interrupt only to its processor, while the PIT raises a global interrupt, which may be handled by any CPU in the system.
what is your comment?

Answer (score 0):

False.  Only one CPU receives the interrupt.